# Populating list with Multiple Text Views

Tags: android, listview

I have a slightly complicated problem. I have a listview (each row contains 3 textviews) that are being populated by a SimpleCursorAdapter, above the listview is a Seekbar. What is meant to happen is when the seekbar is moved the value of the middle textview should change (value of middle textview * seekbar.getProgress()).

In order to do this I have created a Cursor that returns the required information from the database, these value are stored in variables and multiplied by the seekbar progress, and finally added into an array

The issue that I am having is populating the listview with the new values within the array. When I slide the seekbar the original values in listview just disappear and no new value are entered into the list.

My question is, how do I populate all 3 of the textviews with the new values in the array into the listview?

**Code**

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
    progress = progresValue;
    textView.setText("Serving Size:" + progress);
    int newServings = seekBar.getProgress();

    //read adapter into array multiplying measurement as you go and display new adapter
    final Cursor ingredient2 = adapter.getRecipesIngredients(recipeCode);
    ingredient2.moveToFirst();
    ArrayList<String> newIngredients = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(ingredient2.moveToNext()) {
        String ingredientName = ingredient2.getString(ingredient2.getColumnIndex("ingredient_name"));
        int newMeasurement = ingredient2.getInt(ingredient2.getColumnIndex("measurement"));
        newMeasurement = newMeasurement * progress;
        String newMes = Integer.toString(newMeasurement);
        String ingredientUnit = ingredient2.getString(ingredient2.getColumnIndex("unit"));
        newIngredients.add(ingredientName);
        newIngredients.add(newMes);
        newIngredients.add(ingredientUnit);
    }
    ingredient2.close();

    ArrayAdapter newList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row4,newIngredients);
    ListView ingredientsRecquired2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ingredientsRequired);
    ingredientsRecquired2.setAdapter(newList);
 }
```

**Listview Row Layout (row5)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ingredientName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ingredientMeasurement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ingredientName"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ingredientUnit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ingredientMeasurement"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are lots of different ways to achieve this. And if i got your question right, you want something like this?

[image: demo]

Here is my version how you can implement this:
Create custom array adapter for your list view and custom Ingredient object to store info from db for each object. Get data from your db once and update view on every SeekBar progress changed in your custom adapter getView method code.

Demo Code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private ListView listView;
    private MyCustomAdapter listViewAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        listViewAdapter =  new MyCustomAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

        updateListDataFromDB();
    }

    private void updateListDataFromDB(){
        ArrayList<Ingredient> data = listViewAdapter.getDataArray();
        data.clear();

        //test data instead of data from db
        data.add(new Ingredient("One", 123, "kg"));
        data.add(new Ingredient("Two", 15, "kg"));
        data.add(new Ingredient("Three", 10, "kg"));

        /*
        final Cursor ingredient2 =  adapter.getRecipesIngredients(recipeCode);

        ingredient2.moveToFirst();

        while(ingredient2.moveToNext()) {
            String ingredientName = ingredient2.getString(ingredient2.getColumnIndex("ingredient_name"));
            int newMeasurement = ingredient2.getInt(ingredient2.getColumnIndex("measurement"));
            String ingredientUnit = ingredient2.getString(ingredient2.getColumnIndex("unit"));
            Ingredient newIngredient = new Ingredient(ingredientName, newMeasurement, ingredientUnit);
            data.add(newIngredient);
        }

        ingredient2.close();
        */

        listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {
        listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private ArrayList<Ingredient> data = new ArrayList<>();
        private Context context;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context){
            this.context = context;
        }

        public ArrayList<Ingredient> getDataArray(){
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Ingredient getItem(int position) {
            return data.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }

            TextView nameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ingredientName);
            TextView measurementView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ingredientMeasurement);
            TextView unitView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ingredientUnit);
            Ingredient ingredient = getItem(position);

            nameView.setText(ingredient.name);
            int currMeasurement = ingredient.measurement * (seekBar.getProgress() + 1); // +1 because seekBar default value is 0;
            measurementView.setText(String.valueOf(currMeasurement));
            unitView.setText(ingredient.unit);

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    private class Ingredient {
        public String name;
        public int measurement;
        public String unit;

        public Ingredient(String name, int measurement, String unit) {
            this.name = name;
            this.measurement = measurement;
            this.unit = unit;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:padding="20dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**row.xml** - same as your Listview Row Layout (row5)

Comment: You should at least use ViewHolder (anti)-pattern - I don't like it, but the code you provided is very inefficient (in context of `findViewById` calls)

Comment: @varren, thank you so much! this is just what I was trying to do! I will award the bounty when I can, says I have to wait 22 more hours

Comment: @Vasiliy nice point. I completely agree. [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) can improve preformace. Just had no desire to complicate code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the "notifyDataSetChanged" method on the adapter to make the changes happen.